# why a instance of function object didn't inherit the function prototype property?

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of code, I am wondering why `boy.new2` is undefined?

```
Object.prototype.new1 = 'h1';
Function.prototype.new2 = 'h2';
function person(){

} 
var boy = new person();
console.log(boy.new1); //h1
console.log(boy.new2); //undefined
```

Comment: It has to be defined inside Person() - an object. this.new1 = 'h1'; or this.new2 = 'h2'; Refer to the other answers as to why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `boy` is not a `Function` instance, so it doesn't inherit from `Function.prototype`:

```
boy instanceof Function; // false
```

The prototypical chain is:

- `boy` inherits from `person.prototype`.
- `person.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`.
- `Object.prototype` inherits from `null`.

If you want `person` instances to inherit from `Function.prototype`, you can do

```js
person.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
person.prototype.constructor = person; /* optional */
```

```js
Object.prototype.new1 = 'h1';
Function.prototype.new2 = 'h2';
function person(){} 
person.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
person.prototype.constructor = person; /* optional */
var boy = new person();
document.body.innerHTML =
  boy.new1   // "h1"
  + '<br />'
  + boy.new2 // "h2"
;
```

Now the prototypical chain is:

- `boy` inherits from `person.prototype`.
- `person.prototype` inherits from `Function.prototype`.
- `Function.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`.
- `Object.prototype` inherits from `null`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer! but I still don't get it why boy is not a Function instance?

Comment: Because `new person()` creates an object which inherits from `person.prototype`. But by default, `person.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype` instead of `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

because the result of the function call isn't a function, it is an object.

`(function() {}).new2` would result in the expected results as you are referencing the function and not the resulting object.

```js
Function.prototype.logger = console.log.bind(console);

(function foo() {}).logger('hello world'); // logs 'hello world'
```

edit: yea, I realized the output doesn't show the logging :P oops. you'll have to open your console to see this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
console.log(typeof boy);
```

the boy var is an Object, not an Function